# What is the math concept that describes efficiencies of doing things in parallel?

Tags: optimization, estimation

Sorry if this is a bit vague, but I am having a discussion with my coworkers that is vaguely familiar, but I cannot recall the name of this class of math problems, so I don't know where to start researching further.

Basically, the problem goes like this:

- Doing X instead of Y saves me 5 minutes.
- I have identified 1,000 other places where we do X.
- My college says that doing Y in all of these places saves 5,000 minutes.  Simple multiplication.  I disagree.
- I'm pretty sure that we don't spend even close to 5,000 minutes total doing all 1,000 instances of X.
- Therefore, there must be some other more complex equation that can help estimate the time actually saved by doing Y for N occurrences.

This is vaguely reminiscent of the argument about buying quantities of a product at a grocery store.  Say I need 1 apple.  I drive to the store, park my car, go into the store, find the apple, put it in my cart, go to the checkout stand, pay for the apple, drive home and enjoy my apple.  Say that takes 30 minutes.  Now say I need 10 apples.  It's not 300 minutes, it's still 10 minutes.  But say I needed 10,000 apples - well that would take longer.  At some point there are other factors to consider.

My direct question is: what class or category of mathematics or statistics concepts should I be relearning to better estimate problems of this nature?

Bonus if you can give me some equations to get started.  Thanks.

P.S. I'm probably way off on what tags I've selected.  Please feel free to edit.

Comment: "Computational complexity" is the general topic.

Comment: Hmmm.. So I'm quite familiar with things like Big-O notation for describing linear vs exponential vs logarithmic complexity in software algorithms.  But I'm thinking more along the lines of human problems.  Is it the same thing?  Can you be more specific?  Maybe an equation that helps with the apple-shopping problem might help me figure out how to apply it to our specific needs.  Many thanks.

Comment: suggest you visit U of W on a weekday. Probably one of the computer -related departments. Ask for someone with office hours that fit when you are there. You need someone who speaks your language and can give you some relevant book titles, websites. Now that I think of it, there will be a department library, or perhaps overall engineering library. A librarian could help a good deal.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_algorithm and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_parallel_algorithms  and references at both